# __block variable changes value

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to search through a list of reminders in order to check if a reminder exists. There is an option in the method to save the value of whether or not the reminder exists. I am using a block, and within the block, when the reminder is found, the new value is assigned to the `reminderExists` variable, like it is supposed to. However, when I enter the save if statement, the value of `reminderExists` has changed from what it was assigned in the block. I am stumped with this issue, and I have tried many changes to diagnose the problem, to no avail. Thanks for any help!

```
- (BOOL)checkForReminderWithTitle:(NSString *)reminderTitle saveChanges:(BOOL)save {

NSNumber *currentGardenCurrentReminders = currentGarden.reminders;
__block NSNumber *reminderExists = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];

if (eventStore == nil)
{
    eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

        if (!granted)
            NSLog(@"Access to store not granted");
    }];
}


if (eventStore != nil) {

    NSPredicate *predicate = [eventStore predicateForIncompleteRemindersWithDueDateStarting:[NSDate distantPast] ending:[NSDate distantFuture] calendars:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewReminders]]];

    [eventStore fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:predicate completion:^(NSArray *reminders) {
        for (EKReminder *reminder in reminders) {

            NSLog(@"%@", reminderTitle);

            if ([reminder.title isEqualToString:reminderTitle]) {

                reminderExists = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                NSLog(@"reminder exists");
                NSLog(@"after reminder exists is assigned to YES, value is %@", ([reminderExists boolValue]) ? @"True" : @"False");
                if ([reminderExists boolValue]) NSLog(@"reminder exists variable works");

                NSArray *alarms = reminder.alarms;

                EKAlarm *alarm = [alarms objectAtIndex:0];

                NSDateFormatter *nextReminderDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                nextReminderDateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy at hh:mm a";
                NSString *nextReminderDateString = [nextReminderDateFormatter stringFromDate:alarm.absoluteDate];

                NSLog(@"Next reminder is on %@", nextReminderDateString);

                break;

            }
        }
    }];

}

if (save && ([currentGardenCurrentReminders boolValue] != [reminderExists boolValue])) {

    if ([reminderExists boolValue]) {
        NSLog(@"within save, reminderexists == true");
    } else NSLog(@"within save, reminderexists == false");

    currentGarden.reminders = reminderExists;
    [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
}

return [reminderExists boolValue];
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call to `fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:completion:` is asynchronous. This means that your `if` statement after this call is actually being done long before the call to `fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:completion:` is complete.

You can't have a useful return value in a method that does asynchronous processing. You need to change your `checkForReminderWithTitle:saveChanges:` method to return `void` and instead have it pass a completion block that will be called when the call to `fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:completion:` is done.

BTW - why is `reminderExists` an `NSNumber` pointer and not just a `BOOL`?

Comment: `reminderExists` was originally a `BOOL`, however, during the debugging process I thought that not using an object might have been part of the problem.

Comment: I have moved my `if (save)` statement inside the block, however, how will I execute the save if my `for` loop never finds the reminder?

Comment: You need the same "save" code if `eventStore == nil`. Create a method with the same logic that you can call from the two places it needs to be called from.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `[EKEventStore fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:completion:]` is asynchronous. So when you check the value of `reminderExists` below the completion block, the completion block may not have executed yet, and `reminderExists` may not yet have the correct value.

To fix the problem, put your check code in the end of the completion block. As @rmaddy correctly points out, this function can't return a value, since it relies on an async call.

Comment: Simply moving the `if` statement inside the block doesn't deal with the fact that this method attempts to return a value that is being calculated asynchronously.

Comment: @rmaddy you're correct sir. I just clarified my answer.